Socket-io disconnect event not getting triggered
So i wanted to make userstatus by updating prisma database on connect event and disconnect event of socket-io in nextjs. The disconnect event is not getting fired. It feels like NextResponse have something to do with it. I am actually a new to this so i am unable to figure how can i do this. If you have any suggestion regarding userstatus or any other way to update database on the disconnect and connect  event the please tell me.(This is the easiest way i can update database,and the only way i can think)
code of io.ts:
import { Server as NetServer } from "http";
import { NextApiRequest } from "next";
import { Server as ServerIO } from "socket.io";

import { NextApiResponseServerIo } from "@/types";
import { db } from "@/lib/db";
import { getAuth } from "@clerk/nextjs/server";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

export const config = {
  api: {
    bodyParser: false,
  },
};

const ioHandler = (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponseServerIo) => {
  if (!res.socket.server.io) {
    const path = "/api/socket/io";
    const httpServer: NetServer = res.socket.server as any;
    const io = new ServerIO(httpServer, {
      path: path,
      // @ts-ignore
      addTrailingSlash: false,
    });
    io.on("connection", socket => {
      socket.on("connect", async () => {
        try {
          console.log("Connected");
          const { userId } = getAuth(req)
          if (!userId) {
            return null
          }
          const currentProfile = await db.profile.findUnique({
            where: {
              userId
            }
          })
          const updateOnline = await db.profile.update({
            where: {
              id: currentProfile?.userId,
            },
            data: {
              Active: {
                set: true,
              }
            }
          })
          return NextResponse.json(updateOnline);
        } catch (error) {
          console.log("[SERVER_ID_LEAVE]", error);
          return new NextResponse("Internal Error", { status: 500 });
        }
      })
      socket.on("disconnect", async () => {
        console.log("disconnect");
        try {
          console.log("Connected");
          const { userId } = getAuth(req)
          if (!userId) {
            return null
          }
          const currentProfile = await db.profile.findUnique({
            where: {
              userId
            }
          })
          const updateOffline = await db.profile.update({
            where: {
              id: currentProfile?.userId,
            },
            data: {
              Active: {
                set: false,
              }
            }
          })
          return NextResponse.json(updateOffline);
        } catch (error) {
          console.log("[SERVER_ID_LEAVE]", error);
          return new NextResponse("Internal Error", { status: 500 });
        }
      })
    })
    res.socket.server.io = io;
  }
  res.end();
}

export default ioHandler;

again, I want your help it will be appreciated. Thanks in advance!!
